# Configure the Cookie Path with a Virtual Directory in AddSession()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, .net-core, kestrel

I would like to set the path of the `.ASPNetCoreSession` cookie to the virtual directory in which the application is currently hosted in. This should of course happen dynamically. Currently the path is set to `/` by default.

```
services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.Path = "/MyVirtual/DirectoryPath";
        options.Cookie.Name = SessionCookieName;
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    });
```

The [anti forgery token implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.cs#L80) already does this out of the box as intended and I would like to do something similar to that.

```
  var pathBase = httpContext.Request.PathBase.ToString();

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathBase))
  {
      options.Path = pathBase;
  }
```

Unfortunately this implementation is bounded to the `HttpContext`.

I was thinking about using `IPostConfigureOptions<T>` or `IConfigureOptions<T>` to make use of DI but as long as I need to access the current `HttpContext` which is scoped I don't see a way to do that.

I am sure there must be other ways to retrieve the virtual directory within the `Startup.cs` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not a huge fan of this option but for the time being I will just add my own [SessionMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/87629bbad906e9507026692904b6bcb5021cdd33/src/Middleware/Session/src/SessionMiddleware.cs#L160) (which is registered as part of `UseSession()` in the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`) where I will retrieve the virtual directory from the `HttpContext` and set `Cookie.Path` via the `CookieBuilder`.